# Inserting letter for words with initial letter sequence

Tags: replace

I would like to introduce the letter `k` for words with initial `cog`, `col`, `com`, `con`, `cor`, `coun`, and `cum` using an elisp command defined in my init file.

That is

```
"cognize" changed to "knize"
"collect" to "klect"
"corrupt" to "krupt"
"cumulatively" to "kulatively"
```

But I cannot simply add these programmatically using such things as `global-abbrev-table`
then doing following

```
(define-abbrev global-abbrev-table "cognize" "knize")
(define-abbrev global-abbrev-table "collect" "klect")
```

Because I cannot end having to do all these defines for every word in the dictionary.  I need some way to look at a word and decide whether `cog` exists and a replacement done to `k`, and so on.

Comment: Are there exceptions? If not, why not do a wholesale regexp substittution?

Comment: No actual exceptions.  Have not worked with regexp substitution in elisp yet.

Comment: As test I want to apply the functionality by taking the word at the cursor position point.

Comment: You should have said that to begin with *IN THE QUESTION*, not in a comment. The answer does a whole-buffer substitution. But I'm feeling charitable, so I'll give you a hint: `C-h f looking-at`. I will ignore any additional questions in comments though.

Comment: Changing a question after an answer has been posted in a way that invalidates the answer is a no-no: don't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So all you have to do is a regexp match:

```el
(replace-regexp "\\<\\(co[glmnr]\\|coun\\|cum\\)" "k")
```

The `\<` says "match an empty string but only at the beginning of a word", so only initial matches count.
The character class `[glmnr]` says "match any one of the characters enclosed in the square brackets", the `\|` is the alternation (`OR`) construct. Note that in the string syntax, backslashes have to be doubled ("escaped").

See [Searching and Replacement](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Search.html) in the Emacs manual. In particular, see the four sections on regexps in that chapter. For the backslash constructs, see [Backslash Regexp](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexp-Backslash.html).

For more details, see [Regular Expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regular-Expressions.html) in the Emacs Lisp reference manual.